# Chrome browser immediately crashes and I cannot get to my bookmarks

Tags: data-recovery, chrome-for-android

Does anyone know why I'm no longer able to access my Mobile Bookmarks on my Galaxy S3 since the last major Android update several months ago? Prior to that update I had no problems with my bookmarks. Now all I get is a "Aw Snap" error message. The bookmark page will appear for a split second then turns into Aw Snap. So aggravating! I don't think the problem is directly within Chrome because I've followed nearly all the online fix instructions others have given to no avail. I think those fixes were for those having Aw Snap issues on their desktops.

My last hope was one giving instructions to add Chrome To Mobile Extension on the desktop first but I was shocked that the Extension is not even a Google product! Needless to say I removed it immediately. I'm a baby neophyte in this tech world... All I want to do is get my Mobile Bookmarks that I've had for the 2 yrs that I've owned my beloved Galaxy S3...

Answer (score 0):

The bookmarks would be synced to Google servers if the browser is signed in. Then try clearing the cache of the app. Uninstall any updates to the app to see if that's causing the issue. If it still crashes, clear the app data, but if the bookmarks aren't synced they'll be erased